# How to change the button name in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to have a code that changes the name of the button when I click on the button, and when I click on it again, it changes its previous name again.

```
const [getName, setName] = useState(false);

        const handleNameChange = () => {
            setName(!getName); 
        }


    <button onClick={handleNameChange}>
           {getName ? 'Inactive' : 'active'}
       </button>
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The execution code does not give an error . Can the code be written using conditional if and else statements? I don't know, unfortunately

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in one line like this .

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    return (
        <button onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
            {isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
        </button>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215918/discussion-on-answer-by-vyas-arpit-how-to-change-the-button-name-in-react).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it like this, should work:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

    export const Button = () => {
      const [getName, setName] = useState(false);
      const handleNameChange = () => {
        setName(!getName);
      };
      return (
        <button onClick={handleNameChange}>
          {getName ? "Inactive" : "active"}
        </button>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rename the state to be more descriptive of what it is doing:

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

const toggle = () => {
  setIsActive(!isActive); 
}

return (
  <button onClick={toggle}>
    {isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
  </button>
);
```

I think this should work though.

Comment: My code is the same, but I don't know why it doesn't run and gives an error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add render function. In this case a return.

```js
const [getName, setName] = useState(false);

const handleNameChange = () => {
   setName(!getName);
};

return (
   <button onClick={handleNameChange}>
     {getName ? "Inactive" : "active"}
   </button>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use setter function on button click. No need to make an extra function.

```
const [getName, setName] = useState(false);

return (
    <button onClick={() => setName(!getName)}>
        {getName ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
    </button>
);
```